# How to install Generic / Text Only printer on Raspberry pi 4 with Windows 10

Tags: pi-4, driver, windows, printing

On windows 10 for Raspberry pi (ARM64), all basic printer drivers are present (microsoft, samsung), but "Generic" section isn't present!

I need to install a thermal receipt printer (exactly Excelvan POS 58mm; code below HOP-E58).

The driver (on normal windows 10) is located here:

> C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\prnge001.inf_amd64_1daeee8f3aa30fcb

I also tried installing the drivers from here

http://www.hoinprinter.com/en/download

Is there any way to install it?

Comment: @goldilocks I am aware of that! They recompiled those ms and samsung but not the "generic"! Moreover, the post is not a "duplicate"! The other one talk about Linux OS

Comment: I apologize -- I really did not look closely at this.  We get so few Windows-on-the-Pi questions and at a glance I only noticed the bit about "on normal Windows", and presumed this was yet another no proprietary driver for Raspbian question.  But the nature of this is obviously different from that.  Again, sorry!